# How can I return EXCLUDED from WITH in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to be able to use the values of the `EXCLUDED` record after handling an `ON CONFLICT`

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table (some_num INT UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO test_table (some_num) VALUES(1);

WITH ex AS (
    INSERT INTO test_table (some_num) VALUES(1)
    ON CONFLICT (some_num) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING EXCLUDED.*
 )
 SELECT * FROM ex;
```

however, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Query Error: error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "excluded"
```

I *believe* this is caused because outside of the `WITH` clause, the `EXCLUDED` table is no longer able to be referenced.  Is there a way to reference the `EXCLUDED` table from outside of the `WITH` clause?

Comment: From the manual `The optional RETURNING clause causes INSERT to compute and return value(s) based on each row actually inserted`.  Use of `EXCLUDED` is too late by then.  What do you want to use this for?  Might a TRIGGER be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more brute-force approach should work.  Store the rows being inserted in a separate CTE.  Then you can remove the ones that are inserted:

```
WITH to_insert (some_num) as (
       VALUES (1), (2), (3)
     ),
    i AS (
     INSERT INTO test_table (some_num)
         SELECT *
         FROM to_insert
         ON CONFLICT (some_num) DO NOTHING
         RETURNING *
    )
 SELECT ti.some_num
 FROM to_insert ti
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM i WHERE i.some_num = ti.some_num);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=73e861722c2ad6bf764bf35ad2b22f75) is a db<>fidde.